# Generating Password protected excel file in Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, rubygems

Is it possible to create a password protected Excel file in Ruby.

The following Gem:
https://github.com/randym/axlsx
helps in "write-protecting" a cell with Password. However, the requirement is to have password protect the entire Excel file, such that the user should not be able to open the workbook without password. Like, the way we can do from Excel itself, "Encrypt with Password" option in Excel.

Anyone knows if there is a Gem out there. Or any code snippets or pointers which could help us to encrypt the Excel file, the way that Microsoft expects.

Comment: I've had a bit of a poke around and i can't see any gems to do this:  some of them can set a password required to modify the file but not as password to prevent it being opened.  The closest i've seen is `roo` https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=password which has functionality to **open** a password-protected spreadsheet, but it doesn't seem to have the ability to set a password on write.  If you can't figure this out, an alternative could be to zip the excel file and have a password on the zip file, which is easier to do programatically.  Pretty crappy substitute though.

Comment: You could try to contact Nilesh Naik from here http://user.poi.apache.narkive.com/TTnB5x2j/adding-password-protection-to-excel-files who was trying to do this 5 years ago - maybe he figured it out.

Comment: I tried to open with a password, but it does not seem to work with .xlsx
I'm not able to open a password protected excel file with roo.
Does anyone know any way to open a .xlsx password protected file using ruby?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a password protected excel files in xxx.zip, unzip the file need password.

```
`zip -P #{password} #{myfile.zip} #{myexcel}.xls`
```